# Understanding Linear Algebra Proof of Division Algorithm for Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

let $p,s \in P(\mathbb{F})$ and $\deg p =n, \deg s = m$ , consider $n\geq m$

Define $T:P_{n-m}(\mathbb{F})\times P_{m-1}(\mathbb{F})\to P_{n}(\mathbb{F})$ as $(q,r)\mapsto sq+r$
suppose $(q,r) \in \ker T$ then $T((q,r))=0$

$\implies sq+r=0$ which means $(q,r)=0$ and hence $\ker T=\{0\}$. Then using Fundamental Thm of Linear maps can complete the proof by noting the dimension of $\dim$ range $T = \dim P_{n}(\mathbb{F})$.

Now, the part I'm not sure if I understand correctly is how $sq+r=0$ imply $(q,r)=0$, if $sq=-r$ then $\dim sq=m+n-m=n\geq m$, then we simply have $sq$ and $r$ to be constant polynomials but I dont see how this means the constant polynomial must be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The degree of $s$ is $m$ and the degree of $p$ is at most $n-m$.

If $p\ne0$, we have
$$
m\le\deg(sp)\le m+(n-m)=n
$$
On the other hand, the degree of $-r$ is at most $m-1$, so $p\ne0$ implies $sp\ne-r$.

Thus $sp=-r$ implies $p=0$ and so also $r=0$.

Answer (score -1):

here is an example  with integer coefficients,   while plenty of fractions show up.  I'll make this CW

$$  \left(   x^{4}  + 2 x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  + 4 x  + 5 \right)  =  \left(  7 x^{3}  + 6 x^{2}  + 5 x  + 4 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 7 x  + 8 }{ 49 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{ 64 x^{2}  + 128 x  + 213 }{ 49 }  \right)  $$
$$  \left(  7 x^{3}  + 6 x^{2}  + 5 x  + 4 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{ 64 x^{2}  + 128 x  + 213 }{ 49 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 343 x  - 392 }{ 64 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{  - 147 x  + 1960 }{ 64 }  \right)  $$
$$  \left(   \frac{ 64 x^{2}  + 128 x  + 213 }{ 49 }  \right)  =  \left(   \frac{  - 147 x  + 1960 }{ 64 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 12288 x  - 188416 }{ 21609 }  \right) } +  \left( \frac{ 119677}{441 } \right)  $$
$$  \left(   \frac{  - 147 x  + 1960 }{ 64 }  \right)  =  \left( \frac{ 119677}{441 } \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 64827 x  + 864360 }{ 7659328 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$
$$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 7 x  + 8 }{ 49 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 7 x  + 8 }{ 49 }  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 343 x  - 392 }{ 64 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 49 x^{2}  }{ 64 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 343 x  - 392 }{ 64 }  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 12288 x  - 188416 }{ 21609 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 192 x^{3}  - 2944 x^{2}  + 63 x  + 72 }{ 441 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 1344 x^{2}  - 19072 x  + 23993 }{ 441 }  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 64827 x  + 864360 }{ 7659328 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 441 x^{4}  + 882 x^{3}  + 1323 x^{2}  + 1764 x  + 2205 }{ 119677 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 3087 x^{3}  + 2646 x^{2}  + 2205 x  + 1764 }{ 119677 }  \right) } $$
$$  \left(   x^{4}  + 2 x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  + 4 x  + 5 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 1344 x^{2}  - 19072 x  + 23993 }{ 119677 }  \right)  -  \left(  7 x^{3}  + 6 x^{2}  + 5 x  + 4 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 192 x^{3}  - 2944 x^{2}  + 63 x  + 72 }{ 119677 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?